# Text Box Moving in SQL Report builder

Tags: sql-server, report-builder2.0, sqlreportingservice

I make a report in report builder that has many text boxes like
[main picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI888.png)

but when I run design view show me like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBsDc.png), all text boxes movie somewhere else

I could not understanding what happen exactly, does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: If you create a box for each line and place your text boxes inside. It will prevent them moving around, as much. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Another option is using tables or lists as the starting point

Answer (score 0):

If this is all continuous text and all text boxes are filled with an expression, then it is recommended to make one large text box with the entire content. A text box can contain any number of expressions.